# Why does Visual Studio Code auto add {" "}?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am working on a React Native App and I noticed some weird behavior in VSCode.

When I write some JSX code and I auto-format it, sometimes the IDE auto adds a " {" "} " between my code.

The app doesn't break, but removing it also doesn't change the behavior of the app.

Is it just a VSCode thing? Is it there so I can read the code better or something?

For example:

This code:

```
return {
    headerTitle: "Favorites",
    headerLeft: <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={CustomHeaderButton}> <Item title="Menu" iconName="md-menu" /> </HeaderButtons>
  }
```

gets changed to:

```
 return {
   headerTitle: "Favorites",
   headerLeft: (
     <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={CustomHeaderButton}>
       {" "}
       <Item title="Menu" iconName="md-menu" />{" "}
     </HeaderButtons>
   )
 };
```

I am using Prettier for code formatting.

Comment: Good question. I also wanted to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's to add an explicit space in your rendered output.  It sees the space in your code:

```
...derButton}> <Item ti...
```

And `{" "}` this ensures a space gets rendered to the output.